# GCP - build error in Docker-php container: npm does not support Node.js v14.17.1

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform

My Dockerfile-php file is failing (GCP build) at the following line, as of this morning (no changes were made to GCP/code relating to containers at all):

```
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        autoconf \
        bzip2-dev \
        curl \
        ffmpeg \
        glib \
        g++ \
        icu-dev \
        libcrypto1.0 \
        libgcc \
        libintl \
        libzip-dev \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libssl1.0 \
        libstdc++ \
        libxext \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxrender \
        libx11 \
        make \
        nodejs \
        nodejs-npm \
        supervisor \
        ttf-dejavu \
        ttf-droid \
        ttf-freefont \
        ttf-liberation \
        ttf-ubuntu-font-family \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) bcmath bz2 intl mbstring opcache pcntl pdo_mysql soap sockets zip \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
    && wget https://storage.googleapis.com/proteus/wkhtmltopdf -O /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \
    && ( \
        cd /tmp \
            && curl -Ls https://storage.googleapis.com/masterstart-platform/files/newrelic-php5-8.7.0.242-linux-musl.tar.gz -o newrelic.tar.gz \
            && tar -xzf newrelic.tar.gz \
            && cd newrelic-* \
            && ./newrelic-install install \
            && cd /tmp \
            && rm newrelic.tar.gz \
    ) \
    && npm install -g mjml \
    && apk del \
        autoconf \
        curl \
        g++ \
        make
```

GCP Error:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.17.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-06-29T10_08_11_471Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories     && apk add --no-cache         autoconf         bzip2-dev         curl         ffmpeg         glib         g++         icu-dev         libcrypto1.0         libgcc         libintl         libzip-dev         libmemcached-dev         libssl1.0         libstdc++         libxext         libxml2-dev         libxrender         libx11         make         nodejs         nodejs-npm         supervisor         ttf-dejavu         ttf-droid         ttf-freefont         ttf-liberation         ttf-ubuntu-font-family     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) bcmath bz2 intl mbstring opcache pcntl pdo_mysql soap sockets zip     && pecl install memcached     && docker-php-ext-enable memcached     && wget https://storage.googleapis.com/proteus/wkhtmltopdf -O /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf     && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf     && (         cd /tmp             && curl -Ls https://storage.googleapis.com/masterstart-platform/files/newrelic-php5-8.7.0.242-linux-musl.tar.gz -o newrelic.tar.gz             && tar -xzf newrelic.tar.gz             && cd newrelic-*             && ./newrelic-install install             && cd /tmp             && rm newrelic.tar.gz     )     && npm install -g mjml     && apk del         autoconf         curl         g++         make' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So looks like I need to use a later version of npm (the versions it's listing as supporting are way below what nodejs is currently at) ...

What is puzzling is in the Dockerfile-php the nodejs package is not specified to be an older version so shouldn't this be referencing the latest nodejs package? How to know which nodejs is being added by apk?

I'm not the author of this docker file and fairly new to Docker containers) any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this has caused a break in this:
https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/commit/25b10bd1a93e12a7e49fee38b0a229281ae49fb7